# Stopwatch fails to reset

Tags: arduino-uno

I am working on an Arduino stopwatch, where it needs a start, stop, and reset button. To reset it, I am using a variable called `starttime` that is updated to equal to `millis()`, and then take the difference to display time. However, past thirty seconds, the `starttime` does not update correctly, and the resulting difference between `starttime` and `millis()` is equivalent to 65 seconds. Can someone explain why this is happening?

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>



LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

const int start = 8;
const int stp = 9;
const int reset = 10;

int seconds;
int minutes;
int timedif;
int starttime = -1;
int timestall = 0;

bool onoff = true;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(start, INPUT);
  pinMode(stp, INPUT);
  pinMode(reset, INPUT);

    lcd.begin(16, 2); //Initialize the 16x2 LCD

    lcd.clear();    //Clear any old data displayed on the LCD

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int bsta = digitalRead(start);//sees if start switch is pressed
  int bstp = digitalRead(stp);//records if stop switch is pressed
  int bres = digitalRead(reset);//records if reset switch is pressed
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Stopwatch");//prints stopwatch top row
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  if (starttime == -1) { //if running first time, time dif is initiated
    starttime = millis();
  }

  timedif = (millis() - starttime )/1000 + timestall; //will get difference in terms of seconds

  minutes = floor(timedif/60); // divides by sixty, drops decimal
  seconds = timedif%60; //gets remainder of divided by 60
  lcd.print(minutes);
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd.print(seconds);
  if (seconds < 10) {
    lcd.setCursor(3,1);
    lcd.print(' ');
  }
  if (bstp == HIGH) {
    onoff = false;
    while(onoff == false) {
      if (digitalRead(start) == HIGH) {
        onoff = true;
      }
    }
    timestall = timedif;
    starttime = millis();
  }
  if (bres == HIGH) {
    delay(100);
    timestall = 0;
    starttime = millis();
    timedif = 0;
    lcd.clear();
    Serial.println("stall:");
    Serial.println(timestall);
    Serial.println("dif");
    Serial.println(timedif);
    Serial.println("start");
    Serial.println(millis() - starttime);


  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `long` or `unsigned long` instead if `int` to declare variables that hold time values.

A `int` variable can only hold 32,767 millisecond hence the 32 sec. where a `long` variable can hold 2,147,483,647 millisecond which is something like 48 days. A `unsigned long` can hold double of that but can not hold a negative value.